# What are the practical effects of the Slovenian government declaring the end of the COVID-19 epidemic?

Tags: covid-19, public-health, slovenia

[This article](https://www.sta.si/2763887/vlada-preklicala-epidemijo-in-odpravila-karanteno-ob-prehodih-meje) from the Slovenian Press Agency published Thursday night states (in Slovenian) that

> **The government has canceled the epidemic and lifted quarantine at border crossings**
>
> At tonight's correspondence session, the government canceled the
>   epidemic of the infectious disease covid-19, which was declared on 12
>   March. The government has also lifted quarantine at external border
>   crossings and at internal border checkpoints, except for persons from
>   third countries with exceptions, the government's communications
>   office said.

What are the practical effects of the status of 'epidemic' no longer being applied by the government? Are the only changes to the state's handling of the virus the lifting of restrictions at the border crossings that the article notes?

Comment: Well, they "did it again" in June [this year](https://www.reuters.com/world/europe/slovenia-declares-end-covid-19-state-emergency-2021-06-15/) so I guess the first "end" didn't last as envisaged... ([According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COVID-19_pandemic_in_Slovenia) the death rate from Covid in Slovenia was in top 4, with the usual caveats that reporting from more developed countries tends to be better...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recent stories from [Reuters](https://www.reuters.com/article/health-coronavirus-slovenia/slovenia-calls-an-end-to-its-coronavirus-epidemic-relaxes-some-border-controls-idUSKBN22R02B), [Balkan Insight](https://balkaninsight.com/2020/05/15/slovenia-declares-victory-over-coronavirus-pandemic/) and [Al-Jazeera](https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2020/05/slovenia-european-nation-declare-epidemic-home-200515084142959.html) lead me to think that the only other significant change coming as a direct result of this declaration is that "**financial aid to citizens and firms hit by the coronavirus, will expire at the end of May**" (per Reuters) instead of being automatically extended (per Al-Jazeera). Otherwise, the government is moving forward with slowly lifting various restrictions, as it was already doing prior to this specific declaration.